# Https Request Using AFNetworking . SNI issue?

Tags: https, afnetworking, sni

I’m posting Https request to our server(the server is in America and I am in China), the certificate is configured right, but now I have some issues:
   In network 4G, everything goes right. When in Wifi, the request always goes to "Time out".  I'm using AFNetworking, someone suggests related to SNI ?  Anyone ever meet this issue? I need your help.

Thanks in advance.